# How do floats create NEW block formatting contexts?

Tags: css, css-float

*Please correct me anywhere as necessary as I'm trying to comprehend this.*

> 9.4.1 Block formatting contexts
>
> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin' properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a block formatting context collapse.
>
> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats).

Interpreting the spec, by default block boxes follow the normal flow positioning scheme.

> Floats, ..., establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

I understand how floats work at a basic level. However, with regards to this spec I'm uncertain how to visualize scenarios under the circumstance of a float being applied. I would appreciate some visual examples.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Where am I suppose to go to discuss this then?

Comment: There may not be a Stack Exchange site suitable. Stack Overflow is for practical answerable problems, not discussions.

Answer (score 3):

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats

In the presence of a float. a sibling block box in the block formatting context simply ignores the float, so its left edge coincides with that of its containing block.

See how in the example below, the blue box occupies the space of the floated image:

```css
body { text-align:center; }
section { display:inline-block; 
          width:200px; }         /* the section establishes a BFC */
img { float:left; opacity: 0.5; height:100px; width:100px; }
div { background-color:blue; height:140px;  }
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="a random image">
  <div></div>
</section>
```

> (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats),

The line boxes that contain the text within the blue div, however avoid the floated image.

```css
body { text-align:center; }
section { display:inline-block; 
          width:200px; }         /* the section establishes a BFC */
img { float:left; opacity: 0.5; height:100px; width:100px; }
div { background-color:blue; height:140px;  
      color:#FFF; text-align:left; }
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="a random image">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</div>
</section>
```

> unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which
>   case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats).

If the sibling box however establishes a new block formatting context, such as because it has `overflow:hidden` applied, then it too will avoid the float and get narrower itself:

```css
body { text-align:center; }
section { display:inline-block; 
          width:200px; }         /* the section establishes a BFC */
img { float:left; opacity: 0.5; height:100px; width:100px; }
div { background-color:blue; height:140px;  
      color:#FFF; text-align:left;
      overflow:hidden; }
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="a random image">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</div>
</section>
```

---

Which explains the text of the quotes in your question body. The question title however, doesn't really make any sense. Float just do establish block formatting contexts for their descendants. It just means that the BFC rules apply there.